When is there a Lipschitz Kantorovich Potential?
Let $c:\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty)$ be a Lipschitz cost function and consider the optimal transport problem
$$
C(\mu,\nu):=\inf_{\pi}\, \int c(x,y)\,\pi(dxdy)
$$
where, as usual, the infimum is taken over all couplings between two given probability measures $\mu,\nu\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
Then, the Kantorovich duality implies that
$$
\tag{1}
\label{1}
C(\mu,\nu) = \sup_{\phi \in L^1(\nu)} \int \phi(u)\,\nu(du) - \int \phi^c(x)\,\mu(dx)
$$
where, $\phi^c$ is given by the infimal convolution $\phi^c:= \inf_x [c(x,y)-\phi(x)]$.

Are the settings where there is some $\phi^{\star}$ realizing \eqref{1} exists and is Lipschitz?  That is, some $L$-Lipschitz $\phi^{\star}:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
C(\mu,\nu) = \int \phi^{\star}(u)\nu(du) - \int (\phi^{\star})^c(v)\mu(dv)?
$$
Is there any relationship between the Lipschitz constant of $c$ and that of $\phi^{\star}$?

Once you have the existence of a solution $\phi$ of (1), you can take $\phi^{cc}$. The objective value of $\phi^{cc}$ is at least that of $\phi$, hence, it is again a solution and further, the $L$-Lipschitz continuity of $c$ implies that $c$-conjugates are $L$-Lipschitz.

@gerw But is it clear when $\phi^{\star}$ is $L$-Lipschitz?

No, but you can replace $\phi$ by $\phi^{cc}$.
